# Confidence limits on a curve fit with algebraically related parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, curve-fitting, constraint

I suspect that the required techniques for my question already exist, but I don't know what the correct nomenclature is - if so apologies, and can someone point me at the right resources?

I have a number of curves that piecewise describe a experimental data set. Some of the constants for these curves are related to each other via analytic forms. For example if I fit two sections of my data using the linear equations $y=m_1.x+c_1$ for one part, and $y = m_2.x+c_2$ for the second part, then $m_2 = m_1^2$ relates the gradients of the two lines.

Fitting $y=m_1.x+c_1$ thus defines $m_2$, and this is easy enough to implement in a fitting algorithm, however the confidence limits on $m_2$ are more problematic. Directly propagating the confidence limits on $m_1$ produces unrealistically large limits, so what do I do instead?

Edit - Sample Data added

I fit the data below x = 2 with a quadratic and above with a linear curve, enforcing continuity (including the first differential) at the intersection.

x = [1.7011 1.7234  1.7266  1.7505  1.8049  1.806   1.8592  1.862   1.8625  1.8663  1.8668  1.9239  1.9565  1.9571  1.962   2.1304  2.1739  2.1739  2.1848  2.1902  2.1902  2.1902  2.2011  2.2717  2.2717  2.288   2.2989  2.3098  2.3098  2.3207  2.3315  2.3533  2.3533  2.3913  2.4674  2.4674  2.4728  2.4728  2.625   2.6304  2.6304  2.6304]

Y = [1.2998 1.3166  1.3233  1.3491  1.3802  1.3891  1.4064  1.4094  1.4214  1.4245  1.4802  1.4843  1.4874  1.5193  1.5209  1.5729  1.6131  1.6214  1.6265  1.6281  1.6298  1.6399  1.6533  1.6667  1.6851  1.7002  1.7052  1.7102  1.7119  1.7119  1.7203  1.727   1.7353  1.7387  1.7437  1.7454  1.7538  1.7755  1.8241  1.8291  1.8325  1.8375]

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: Data added, sorry for the delay,  I was outside cell reception all day.

Comment: It's just the delta-method.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, I found that a quadratic logarithmic equation "y = a + b * log(x) + c * pow(log(x), 2.0)" (where log is the natural log) seems to fit the entire range of the posted data fairly well, with parameters a = 3.0496816334683524E-01, b = 2.2339160821508095E+00, and c = -6.8066648613654057E-01 yielding R-squared = 0.9914 and RMSE = 0.01457

[image: plot]